# Pointer pointing to an empty array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have a pointer that is pointing to the start of an array, but I need to check that it is unallocated. I thought of dereferencing the pointer and checking if NULL but that leads to a type error. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

```
int mydispose(int *array){
    int i = 0;

    if(*array == NULL){
            return 1;
    }

    return ;
```

}

EDIT: Sorry if I was unclear: I have a pointer that points to the start of an array, but I wish to check whether the array is empty.

Comment: -1? The question shows a lack of understanding, but that's the whole point of asking questions. The code is formatted and the question is clear. If you're going to downvote someone, at least say why.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`*array == NULL` is wrong. You are dereferencing the pointer first (which could lead to a segfault if the pointer really is null) and then comparing its int value to a pointer value. Moreover, your compiler will perfectly accept that erroneous expression if `NULL` is defined as just `0` and not `(void *) 0`.

You should be checking `array == NULL` to see if the passed pointer refers to anything, and then dereference it only in case it's not `NULL`.

Be aware, however, that dereferencing a non-null pointer isn't guaranteed to be a safe operation either. If the pointer contains a garbage value because it was allocated on the stack and not initialized, or if it refers to a deallocated region of memory, nasty bugs can happen.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I had originally thought, but doesn't this just show me that I have a null pointer, rather than a pointer pointing to an empty array?

Comment: There is no such thing as an empty array in C - when passing arrays to functions you should always pass a number that indicates the length. If that number is zero, you could treat the array as empty. There is the notion, however, of an empty string, because by convention strings are delimited with a zero character at the end. If the first character is a zero character, that is considered an empty string.

Comment: Okay, thanks BB, so maybe I should test for a zero char? I'm rewriting malloc(), "This function will return 1 if array has the form of a correctly initialised structure with no
currently allocated blocks, otherwise it will return 0."

Comment: The alternative to keeping the length of an array separately is adopting the string convention, but that is not always applicable because the "magic" terminating value may as well be a valid, meaningful value, and that implies always allocating at least one element.

Answer (score 5):

You want `if (array == NULL)` -- but unless you first initialize `array` to `NULL`, it won't do any good either. I think you'd be better off backing up and telling us a bit more about what you're trying to accomplish, and trying to get help trying to accomplish your overall goal.

Comment: This. *"...I know I need to do Foo, but don't understand how..."* is often a sign that you *don't* need to do Foo, but something else entirely.

Comment: @dmckee: Yes, exactly. This is especially likely when/if `Foo` is something almost nobody ever needs to do...

Answer (score 1):

The only safe way to determine the allocation status of `*array` is to:

1. Make sure `*array` is set to NULL is not allocated. `int *array = NULL;`
2. Check if the array is NULL: `if (array == NULL) return -1;`

Answer (score 1):

You can't reliably check if some memory location is allocated. `*array` is not a valid code, because it's the same as `array[0]`, but `array[0]` is not allocated. Non-allocated memory location can contain *any* value.

The only option is to ensure that you get the information whether the array is allocated alongside with your array. A popular option is representing unallocated array as `NULL`, but you may choose other option as well.

By the way, there is a difference between an empty array (that is, array of size 0), and array which is not allocated at all. The first option occurs when you use `malloc(0)`, the second when your pointer is not initialized at all. For `malloc(0)` it's allowed to return `NULL`, but it's allowed to return a non-NULL pointer (which you however can't dereference) as well. Both ways are valid according to the standard.

Answer (score 1):

The immediate problem with your code is that you dereferencing `array` before comparing it to NULL.  The type of the *expression* `*array` is `int`, not `int *`.  Leave off the dereference operator and the types will match:

```
if (array == NULL) {...}
```

Note that an uninitialized pointer is only guaranteed to contain NULL if it was declared with static extent (i.e. it was either declared at file scope or with the `static` keyword in front of it).  Similarly, calling `free` on a pointer won't set that pointer value to NULL; it will contain the same pointer value as before, but it will now be invalid.

Answer (score 0):

You must use it like this:

```
if(array == NULL) ...
```